# System.OutOfMemory Exception when reading 1 MB file

Tags: c#, .net, file, io

I've checked other posts and haven't found a way to fix this problem.

```
public string Profile(string FileName,byte[] Search, uint align)
{
    string Result = "";        
    Stream fs = File.OpenRead(FileName);
    byte[] _Search = new byte[Search.Length];
    uint check = 0;
    byte Check_Zero;

    for (uint i = 0; i < fs.Length; i++)
    {
        _Search = func.ReadBytes(FileName, i, _Search.Length);
        if (func.ByteArrayCompare(_Search, Search))
        {
            check = i + align;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (uint i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        Check_Zero = func.ReadByte(FileName, check);
        if (Check_Zero == 0)
            check++;
        else
        {
            Result = func.ReadString(FileName, check);
            break;
        }
    }
    return Result;
}
```

I am attempting to read from two different files. I have no issues when reading from a file that is 9.52KB, but when I try to read from a file that is 1.00MB I get the OutOfMemory exception.

If it helps, here is the ReadBytes(); function I used

```
public static byte[] ReadBytes(string filename, uint address, int length)
{
    var buff = new byte[length];
    Stream fs = File.OpenRead(filename);
    BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(fs);
    b.BaseStream.Seek(address, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    b.Read(buff, 0, length);//This is where it breaks.
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - what system is this running under?  A scripting language or something ancient, maybe.

Comment: For starters, why do you open two streams the file and why don't you have a `using()` statement on the streams to dispose of them properly? Open the file once, read from it and then dispose of the stream.

Comment: are you sure it's only 1Mb and not 1Gb? check the size of Search.

Comment: `Dispose` your streams when you are done `using` them for starters

Comment: And second it would be better to open a single stream and pass it to `ReadBytes` rather than keep reopening the same file multiple times.

Comment: You open a `fs` stream in the first method, but not read from it.

Comment: You seem to be reading Search.Length bytes for each byte in the file - that's not an efficient way of doing things. Read the whole thing into a buffer up front and search in that.

Comment: @Michael Dorgan - Not sure I understand your question? I'm running Windows 8.1 using Visual Studio 15, this is C# language. My system as a whole has 24GB of RAM

Comment: @Ian mercer I've neve rused a using() statement, nor have I "disposed of them properly" I'll do some research into this. Thank you.

Comment: @Gusman, Yes, I am certain of the filesize

Comment: @Matt Bruland I adjusted that and am using a single filestream now, thank you. I am still however getting the same error

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I made that adjustment, thank you :)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the _Search.Length is for the byte length, and it is done to make sure I'm not using a larger array than what is needed. the first for loop grabs the file size in fs.Length;

Comment: Out of Memory happens more often in embedded systems where RAM is not plentiful, though one usually does not see C# used there.  I've also seen it used in Unity as a scripting language so I wanted to be sure of your development env.

Comment: @BrandonPrintiss Can you share a crashing example on [.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)?

Comment: @BrandonPrintiss: My point was that if your file is 1MB you then call `func.ReadBytes` one million times, each time allocating a buffer, which is the length of the search pattern. Yes, those buffers do get garbage collected, but not right away.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I see what you are saying now, Sorry if I came off as snide or rude.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Good to know, I'm still curious to know why I get this error when my system has 24GB of RAM to play with. Perhaps it has to do with some sort of default embedded with VS?

Comment: To everyone, I tried something I am embarrased to admit... The file was the wrong format entirely... There is a folder with files of the same extension (in this case .arkprofile) but in one folder, the file is done completely different, so the error came about when the search function coulnd't find a reference anywhere.

I feel sorry to wasting everybody's time, but I have most definitely learned a few things! So for that I thank you all!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is caused by yor `ReadBytes` implementation. It is called 1 000 000 times for 1MB file and inside it opens the file each time and does not close the file so you are leaking [unmanaged handles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2(v=vs.110).aspx). `File.OpenRead` returns a very special Stream i.e. `FileStream` which has to be explicitly disposed in order to prevent the leakage.

One way to fix that is to use the static method `File.ReadAllBytes`. No need to dispose of anything in that case.

Better way is to open the file once and pass the FileStream reference into your `ReadBytes` function instead of the `filename`. Do not forget to explicitly dispose of it in the end. For instance use the `using` statement. Doing so you will see that your `ReadBytes` function is now 1 line and a very simple one so you do not need that function altogether and your code became faster and easier.